# What is wrong with this Wasserstein GAN?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I have been trying to train a [Wasserstein GAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_GAN) on some data using Tensorflow, and I haven't been able to get the model to output meaningful results.

I've been training on:

- the [**Pix2Pix Facades**](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vikramtiwari/pix2pix-dataset) dataset
- as well as my own data

for a while—to no avail.

The loss functions are really weird, which makes me question if there's something big I am missing with my implementation of my generator/critic model or the calculation of my loss functions.
Here is my architecture of my GAN:

```
OUTPUT_CHANNELS = 1

def downsample(filters, size, apply_batchnorm=True, const=None):
  initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(42)
  result = tf.keras.Sequential()
  result.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, size, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer, use_bias=False, kernel_constraint=const))
  if apply_batchnorm:
    result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
  result.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
  return result

def upsample(filters, size, apply_dropout=False):
  initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(42)
  result = tf.keras.Sequential()
  result.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, size, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer, use_bias=False))
  result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
  if apply_dropout:
      result.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
  result.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
  return result

def Generator():
  inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[256, 256, 1])

  down_stack = [
    downsample(64, 4, apply_batchnorm=False),  
    downsample(128, 4),  
    downsample(256, 4), 
    downsample(512, 4), 
    downsample(512, 4), 
    downsample(512, 4), 
    downsample(512, 4),
    downsample(512, 4), 
  ]

  up_stack = [
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True), 
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True), 
    upsample(512, 4), 
    upsample(256, 4),
    upsample(128, 4),
    upsample(64, 4), 
  ]
  initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(42)
  last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(OUTPUT_CHANNELS, 4, strides=2, padding='same', kernel_initializer=initializer, activation='tanh')

  x = inputs

  skips = []
  for down in down_stack:
    x = down(x)
    skips.append(x)

  skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

  for up, skip in zip(up_stack, skips):
    x = up(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, skip])

  x = last(x)

  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)


def Discriminator():
  const = None
  inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[256, 256, 1], name='input_image')
  tar = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[256, 256, 1], name='target_image')
  initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(42)

  x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([inp, tar])
  x1 = tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.1)(x)
  down1 = downsample(64, 4, False, const)(x1)
  down2 = downsample(128, 4, const)(down1) 
  down3 = downsample(256, 4, const)(down2)
  zero_pad1 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(down3)  
  conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 4, strides=1, kernel_initializer=initializer, use_bias=False, kernel_constraint=const)(zero_pad1)  
  batchnorm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv)
  leaky_relu = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(batchnorm1)
  zero_pad2 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(batchnorm1)
  last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 4, strides=1, kernel_initializer=initializer, kernel_constraint=const)(zero_pad2)
  final = tf.keras.layers.Activation('linear')(last) 
  return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp, tar], outputs=final)
```

Here is my loss function calculations:

```
LAMBDA = 0

def generator_loss(disc_generated_output, gen_output, target):
    target = tf.cast(target, tf.float32)
    target = tf.expand_dims(target, axis=-1)
    gan_loss = wasserstein_loss(tf.ones_like(disc_generated_output), disc_generated_output)
    gan_loss = gan_loss / N_GPU
    gan_loss = gan_loss * -1
    l1_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(target - gen_output))
    l1_loss = l1_loss / N_GPU
    total_gen_loss = gan_loss + (LAMBDA * l1_loss)
    total_gen_loss = tf.convert_to_tensor(total_gen_loss, dtype=tf.float32)
    return total_gen_loss, gan_loss, l1_loss
def discriminator_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output):
    total_disc_loss = wasserstein_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output) / N_GPU
    return total_disc_loss
def wasserstein_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(y_true, y_pred))
def validation_loss(model, test_input, target):
    prediction = model(test_input, training=True)
    prediction = tf.cast(prediction, tf.float64)
    target = tf.cast(target, tf.float64)
    target = tf.expand_dims(target, axis=-1)
    l1_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(target - prediction))
    l1_loss = l1_loss / N_GPU
    return l1_loss
```

Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is not a WassersteinGAN, as neither the loss nor the architecture contain any component to ensure Lipschitz continuity of the discriminator, a crucial component of WassersteinGANs.